# Reusable Copy To Clipboard Function

Tags: javascript, copy, clipboard

I created a reusable copy function that works on any input field with a specific class, but the only way I've been able to pass the value in the input field is by tacking an onclick event directly onto the input field `onclick="copyIt(this)"`, which is obviously not ideal.

When I try to pass the value of the text field to the function is when I get an error: `copyIt(e.target.value);` I should be able to figure this one out, but I'm having no luck. There's obviously/apparently something that I don't understand about how the value needs to be formatted to make this work, but that's the holdup. Any insight would be much appreciated!

```
const copyIt = function (text) {
  text.select();
  console.log("Copied to clipboard");
  document.execCommand("copy");
}

document.querySelectorAll(".copier").forEach((copied) => {
  copied.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value, "event listener attached");
    copyIt(e.target.value);
  });
});
```

https://codepen.io/NoahBoddy/pen/MWJmgQz

Comment: Your codepen works for me...

Comment: @MichaelPaccione That's because it's using an onclick event tacked on to each input field. I'm trying to remove that dependency and do that part with JavaScript. That's what I can't figure out...

Comment: I added a second example that doesn't have the workaround I used so it does NOT work as is: https://codepen.io/NoahBoddy/pen/KKamwoW Sorry for any confusion!

Comment: Just use `e.target`, not `e.target.value`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that text.select() is expecting to select a NodeElement and you're passing in the text itself. You cannot do that so I have adjusted your code to work.

Kudos on forEach across the NodeElements... I have for the longest time done Array.from(NodeList) and this approach brought some alternative insight. Thanks.

```
const copyIt = function (nodeElement) {
  nodeElement.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
}

document.querySelectorAll(".copier").forEach((nodeElement) => {
  nodeElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
    copyIt(nodeElement)
  });
});
```

Comment: so all that was missing from my original version was `copyIt(copied);` instead of `copyIt(e.target.value);` .... I could have sworn I tried that, but maybe not! Regardless, thanks so much for your assistance. Very much appreciated, sir!

Comment: Here's a link to the working version, if anyone else is interested: https://codepen.io/NoahBoddy/pen/KKamwoW